# Migration from MySQL to MySQLi extension

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I have a script written in Mysql that just lists people's names. It works fine in mysql but i have been trying to get it to update to mysqli and i got most of it. However, the results are supposed to be paginated. The pagination works fine because there should be 5 pages and thats where it stops....but ALL of the results just show up on every page. Not sure what i am doing...any help would be greatly appreciated....I know it has to do with "mysql_result"

Here is my new code in mysqli:

```
<?php
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page

$per_page = 10;         // number of results to show per page
$result = $con->query("SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName FROM employee;");
//If Database Error...Print the error and exit
if (!$result) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}
//If No Database Error.....Continue   
if ($result)
{
// Return the number of rows in result set
$total_results=mysqli_num_rows($result);
//printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$total_results);
// Free result set
}
//total pages we going to have
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);
//if page is setcheck
$show_page='';
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$show_page = $_GET['page'];//it will telles the current page
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
$start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
$end = $start + $per_page;
} else {
// error - show first set of results
$start = 0;              
$end = $per_page;
}
} else {
// if page isn't set, show first set of results
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}
// display pagination
$page = intval(isset($_GET['page']));
$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
$page = 1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>View All Employees</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#"><img src="../admin/images/logo-thompson-industrial-services.gif" class="text-   center"width="259" height="59" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<div class="mini-layout">
<?php
$reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;
echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
if ($total_pages > 1) {
echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
}
echo "</ul></div>";
// display data in table
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>";                    
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
// make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
if ($i == $total_results) {
break;
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['EmployeeID'];
$fname = $row['FirstName'];
$lname = $row['LastName'];
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td class="col-md-4">' .$fname .'</td>';
echo '<td class="col-md-4">' .$lname .'</td>';
echo "</tr>";  
}
}
// close table>
echo "</table>";            
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my original code in mysql:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
include('config.php');    //include of db config file
include ('paginate.php'); //include of paginat page

$per_page = 10;         // number of results to show per page
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee");
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);//total pages we going to have

//-------------if page is setcheck------------------//
$show_page='';
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$show_page = $_GET['page'];             //it will telles the current page
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages) {
$start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
$end = $start + $per_page;
} else {
// error - show first set of results
$start = 0;              
$end = $per_page;
}
} else {
// if page isn't set, show first set of results
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
}
// display pagination
$page = intval(isset($_GET['page']));

$tpages=$total_pages;
if ($page <= 0)
$page = 1;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>View Employees</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#"><img src="../admin/images/logo-thompson-industrial-services.gif" class="text-center"width="259" height="59" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<div class="mini-layout">
<?php
$reload = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?tpages=" . $tpages;
echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
if ($total_pages > 1) {
echo paginate($reload, $show_page, $total_pages);
}
echo "</ul></div>";
// display data in table
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>";
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
// make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
if ($i == $total_results) {
break;
}

// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'FirstName') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'LastName') . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}       
// close table>
echo "</table>";
// pagination
?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am doing something wrong here and i cant figure it out....

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please try to boil your code down to the minimum example which still exhibits the problem; this not only helps us, but may help you find the answer on your own. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am trying to convert myqsl_result into mysqli....it is working but the results all show up on the same page...instead of paginatd

Comment: There's a lot missing: where do all the variables come from? E.g. `$total_results`.

Comment: I will edit the question to show the variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also just remove the while statement and use `mysqli_data_seek` in conjunction with `mysqli_fetch_accoc`. The **MySQLi_data_seek** points to the result I need. Check it out:

```
// display data in table
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>First 

Name</th> <th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>"; 
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
// make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
if ($i == $total_results) {
break;
}

//go to the column you want the results 
mysqli_data_seek($result, $i);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// echo out the contents of the row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['LastName'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";  
}

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Did you check out the other solution ? What happened with that answer. Yes I ll up vote you q.

Comment: The other solution did not work.  It still listed all names on each of the pages....it would paginate....but all the names showed up on every page.  This one worked perfect though....again...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are extracting the query is the problem. Once you enter the `while statement` it does not leave until all the results are done and then it executes

```
if ($i == $total_results) {
    break;
}
```

So it never gets a chance to end at $i greater than $total_result. The fix is to include `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in the query. That means you have to fix the pagination page too.

So just run the query again like:

```
// display data in table
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>First 

Name</th> <th>Last Name</th></tr></thead>"; 
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
// run the query again

    $sql ="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName FROM employee LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $end;
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['EmployeeID'];
        $fname = $row['FirstName'];

        $lname = $row['LastName'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td class="col-md-4">' .$fname .'</td>';
        echo '<td class="col-md-4">' .$lname .'</td>';
        echo "</tr>";  
    }

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I need to look at the pagination code. But yeah I can help